# Win32: Synchronisation for day-based unique incremental ids

Tags: windows, winapi, synchronization, ipc

Generating unique incrementing integer ids within the confines of a single Windows box is simple and efficient: shared memory, `InterlockedIncrement()`, end of story. Things get trickier when the ids are bigger than a single integer and/or more complex.

For historical/continuity reasons, one part of a network service requires unique incrementing ids (counters) per day, with day and counter being integers. The day is based on the time of request arrival at the frontend server, whereas the ids are generated by individual worker processes. This means that requests for new ids can happen out of order: ids for yesterday can be requested after the first ids for today have been dispensed already.

Wrapping two counters (one for odd days and one for evens) in a mutex solves the problem adequately, so that's what I'll do for production.

However, the situation is particular in that the day part of the id is guaranteed to change only once every 24 hours, i.e. for more than 99.999% of the time a simple InterlockedIncrement() of a shared integer would be sufficient. Hence I was wondering what a closer-fitting solution would look like, for purely educational purposes.

Here's some pseudo code I've come up with:

```c
SomeMutex id_mutex;
DayBasedId counters[2];  // shared memory counter records for odd and even days

// ...

int get_new_id (int today)
{
   DayBasedId *counter = counters + (julian_day_number(today) & 1);

   if (InterlockedCompareExchange(&counter->day, 0, 0) != today)
   {
      acquire(id_mutex);

      if (counter->day != today)
      {
         counter->day = today;
         counter->val = 0;
      }

      release(id_mutex);
   }

   return InterlockedIncrement(&counter->val);
}
```

The `InterlockedCompareExchange()` thing is intended to force a memory barrier (acquire semantics); it's something I've seen used but is it appropriate? Is the overall synchronisation scheme solid?